# When did these cows brew gins in a hurry?

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer is a year, find it by working out this clue:

> The cows first subtract one, almost too rushed brew gins?

Comment: Which one's the actual clue? The title or the text? Could you change your title to be less confusing? The bulk of the puzzle should be in the description.

Comment: Is that "too" suppose to be "two"? Also this *confusing* is *question*...

Comment: @Deusovi The text is the clue, the title is just a catchy paraphrasing of the clue. I've edited it to make it clear. And 'too rushed' is not a typo.

Comment: @jhabbott There is "23, 23?" letters, coincidence?

Comment: @Daedric yes, although the clue leads to two words, which will lead to the year, so the comma is important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*The cows first subtract one,*

> Cows are cattle, and if we move the first letter back one we get **battle**.

*almost too rushed brew gins?*

> Being too rushed can lead to being hasty. If we remove the last letter and add an anagram of "gins", we get **Hastings**.

Putting them together, the clue indicates

> the Battle of Hastings, which took place in **1066**.